# How can i implement a drag selection for User Controls in my Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

[image]

This is a Sample Image that i made with my non-existing Paint skills...
I have multiple UserControls in my Grid as Child Objects, now i want to implement a Drag Select Function, so if a User Control is selected, it gets a Border.

How can i do this?

Comment: You could just use a simple Rectangle and draw it. Use the MouseDown, Up and Move events for that

Comment: Okay thanks for your answer but how can i detect if the rectangle is over a User Control. I could check all positions from each User Control when the rectangle move event runs but this would be a overkill i think...

Comment: why would it? That's a really quick computation. just check if any user control intersacts your rectangle and that's it. That's how it works ;)

Comment: Ok, i will try it when im home.

Comment: did it work for you?